# Creating a path in a plugin to call a function

Tags: plugin-development, permalinks

Okay, let's assume that I want to create a dynamic "printable" page using a system that doesn't play well with wordpress's theming engine, is there a way for me to define a "permalink" in my plugin that will call a predefined function, also in my plugin?

If you're familiar with Drupal it's similar to how their hook_menu works, but I only need it on a very limited basis, so it doesn't have to be that robust.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along the lines of this would probably do it:

```
function wpse21372_init(){
  add_rewrite_rule( 'your-page-regex/?$', 'index.php?wpse21372=1', 'top' );
  add_rewrite_tag( '%wpse21372%', '([^&]+)' );
}

add_action( 'wp', 'wpse21372_wp' );

function wpse21372_wp( $wp ){
  if( isset( $wp->query_vars['wpse21372'] ) && !empty( $wp->query_vars['wpse21372'] ) ){
    //You're on your custom page.
    //you may want to exit page
    //execution when you're done
    //so the rest of WordPress'
    //normal execution doesn't take
    //over from here.
  }
}
```

After you're done adding that code, make sure you flush the rewrite rules by going to Settings -> Permalinks.

Comment: Looks good, I'm going to test it out and let you know, thanks

Comment: Can't get the rewrite rule to work, but that's fine, no end user will ever see this query string, and just checking the query for the appropriate value using the wp action hook works great, thanks again!

Comment: actually, I had to use `add_rewrite_tag('%my_var%','([^&]+)');` for it to work btw:)

Comment: Of course! I'll add it to my answer so we have it all together.